# How to set up a conditional required attribute in an input inside a component? Reactjs / Nextjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

I Have a simple component that wraps the label and the input together.
I need like in every form, to some inputs to be required and others to not, but you can't pass a parameter to the `required` attribute, so you can't give it a `true` or `false`. And it gets always the attribute.

This is the component:

```
function Input({ type, name, placeholder, required }) {

    return (
        <div className="inputContainer">
            <input placeholder={placeholder} type={type} name={name} required={required ? 'true' : 'false'} />
            <label htmlFor={name}>{placeholder}</label>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And this is the calling:

```
<Input type='text' name='Name' placeholder='Name' required={false} />
```

What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: Actually instead of true or false the input element will require the field even if the required is set to false ... the correct way is to add or remove the attribute depending on the value

Comment: That's what i'm asking :), you can't give it a true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly something like this?

You can try and render one of two different inputs depending on your required prop, which are almost identical except for one not having the required attirbute

```
function Input({ type, name, placeholder, required }) {

    return (
        <div className="inputContainer">
            {required ? <input placeholder={placeholder} type={type} name={name} required /> : <input placeholder={placeholder} type={type} name={name}/>}
            <label htmlFor={name}>{placeholder}</label>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Also if you set the required attribute equal to a boolean, and not a string it should work

```
function Input({ type, name, placeholder, required }) {

    return (
        <div className="inputContainer">
            <input placeholder={placeholder} type={type} name={name} required={required} /> 
            <label htmlFor={name}>{placeholder}</label>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: It would really help if your answer contained some explanantion

Comment: Thanks. The second option works well. The reason i asked this is because the first option has a lot of code, and the component has more complexity than the component that i showed. That's why i asked what it's the best way.